# Is there a way to change the JComboBox's items focus?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I can change the item's focus by pressing the arrow keys on the keyboard or by moving the mouse over it. Is there a programmatic way to move the focus around the items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply set the selected item. Optionally, you can show the dropdown list:

```
comboBox.requestFocus();
comboBox.showPopup();
comboBox.setSelectedIndex(selectedIndex);
```